# How to highlight C-like Code using CodeMirror?

Tags: codemirror

I am using codeMirror to highlight C program code. I followed the official document  to configure:

```
$(".cCodeMirror").each(function(){
  var cEditor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea($(this)[0], {
         lineNumbers: true,
         matchBrackets: true,
         mode: "text/x-csrc",
         readOnly: true,
         styleActiveLine: true,
         theme: "eclipse"
       });
});
```

But I can see the code as follows:
[image]

Notice no syntax is highlighted such as int keyword looks plain text, printf() function is plain text and so on. What am I missing? here is the live url: [here](http://bangla.codingpractise.com/%E0%A6%B8%E0%A6%BF-%E0%A6%AA%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%97%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%82/%E0%A6%AA%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%A5%E0%A6%AE-%E0%A6%B8%E0%A6%BF-%E0%A6%AA%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%97%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%AE/)

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to add the `clike.js` and `eclipse.css`?

Hosted by cdnjs:

- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.42.2/theme/eclipse.min.css
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.42.2/mode/clike/clike.min.js

DEMO: https://codepen.io/quic5/pen/ebMKNV